# Enviar a base de datos según el index

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Hola tengo intención de pasar varios campos a base de datos con un for segun el index. Resulta que al ser un for tiene un indice del 0 al 4 y claro se pasan varios pero al pasarlo a base de datos me salta el siguiente error Notice: Undefined index: tr_dia_lunes

**PHP _ FORM**

```
  for ($l=0; $l<5; $l++){
              echo "<td><input type='text' id='dia_lunes_$l' name='tr_dia_lunes_$l' value='$flunes'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' min='0' id='tr_fase_lunes_$l' name='tr_fase_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='text' id='descripcion_lunes_$l' name='tr_descripcion_lunes_$l' value=''></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_ht_control_lunes' onchange='sumar_ht_control_lunes(),total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), dividir_control_ar_lunes(), total_fila_global(), total_fila_global_ht_control(), total_fila_global_ar_control();' id='ht_control_lunes_$l' name='tr_ht_control_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_unidades_control_lunes' onchange='sumar_unidades_control_lunes(), total_fila_global(), total_fila_lunes($preu_hora),total_fila_global_u_control();' id='unidades_control_lunes_$l' name='tr_unidades_control_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_hh_control_lunes' onchange='total_fila_lunes_tot($l,$preu_hora),sumar_hh_control_lunes(),total_fila_global_hh_control(),total_fila_global(), total_fila_global_ar_control(),total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), total_fila_global(), dividir_control_ar_lunes();' id='hh_control_lunes_$l' name='tr_hh_control_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_ht_no_control_lunes' onchange='sumar_ht_no_control_lunes(),total_fila_lunes_tot($l,$preu_hora),total_fila_global_ht_no_control(), total_fila_lunes($preu_hora);' id='ht_nocontrol_lunes_$l' name='tr_ht_nocontrol_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_hh_no_control_lunes' onchange='sumar_hh_no_control_lunes(),total_fila_global_hh_no_control(), total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), total_fila_global();' id='hh_nocontrol_lunes_$l' name='tr_hh_nocontrol_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_ht_indirect_lunes' onchange='sumar_ht_indirect_lunes(),total_fila_lunes_tot($l,$preu_hora),total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), total_fila_global();' id='ht_indirect_lunes_$l' name='tr_ht_indirect_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_hh_indirect_lunes' onchange='sumar_hh_indirect_lunes(),total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), total_fila_global();' id='hh_indirect_lunes_$l' name='tr_hh_indirect_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_ht_fest_lunes' onchange='sumar_ht_fest_lunes(),total_fila_lunes_tot($l,$preu_hora),total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), total_fila_global();' id='ht_fest_lunes_$l' name='tr_ht_fest_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='suma_hh_fest_lunes' onchange='sumar_hh_fest_lunes(),total_fila_lunes($preu_hora), total_fila_global();' id='hh_fest_lunes_$l' name='tr_hh_fest_lunes_$l' value='0'></td>";
              echo "<td><input type='number' class='total_fila_lunes' id='total_lunes_$l' name='tr_total_lunes_$l' value='0'>€</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
}
```

**PHP INSERTBD**

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])){
  $id_op = $_POST['operari_sel'];
  $fecha_semana = $_POST['fecha_semana'];
    for ($l = 0; $l < 5; $l++) {
      $tr_dia_lunes = $_POST['tr_dia_lunes_'+$l];
    }

 $sql_ins="INSERT INTO inn_document_treballador_pieles_semanal VALUES (NULL, '$id_op', '$fecha_semana', '$tr_dia_lunes');";


}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal como tienes la consulta final, tan solo se insertará el último elemento del for, es decir, el `4`, porque has puesto la consulta **fuera** del bucle.

Fíjate como la tienes:

```php
   for ($l = 0; $l < 5; $l++) {
      $tr_dia_lunes = $_POST['tr_dia_lunes_'+$l];
    }

 $sql_ins="INSERT INTO inn_document_treballador_pieles_semanal VALUES (NULL, '$id_op', '$fecha_semana', '$tr_dia_lunes');";
```

De este modo, estás asignando y sobreescribiendo la variable `$tr_dia_lunes` en cada ciclo, y cuando termine el bucle tan solo contendrá el resultado de la última asignación, que se corresponderia con este `$_POST['tr_dia_lunes_4']`. Ese es un problema aparte, pero que debes considerar arreglar tambien, a menos que ya lo quieras así, ante lo cual no necesitarias el `for` pues podrias llamar al $_POST con su clave directamente.

Y aquí tenemos el problema de tu pregunta, que no estas concatenando bien, pues usas el signo `+` para ello, cuando en PHP se usa normalmente el simbolo `.` (punto).

Es decir, debes ponerlo así:

```php
$tr_dia_lunes = $_POST['tr_dia_lunes_'.$l];
```

para que funcione bien ese índice.

**Nota:** Si la consulta tiene que ser un sumatorio de los valores pasados en las cinco claves `'tr_dia_lunes_'` entonces seguramentete has equivocado de variable en el post y debes usar la numérica denominada `tr_fase_lunes_` y entonces la consulta ya esta bien **fuera** del `for` pero entonces debes modificar la asignación de este modo:

```php
$tr_dia_lunes += $_POST['tr_fase_lunes_'.$l];
```

para que vaya sumandose, y si eso te da error, que es probable, entonces **antes** del bucle inicializa primero la variable con esto:

```
$tr_dia_lunes = 0;
```

Ya nos contaras que tal.

Comment: Es perfecta la solución pero, si tengo 5 fases solo a base de datos me envia 1 y deberia enviar 5 ya que si $l es un for de 0 a 5. i en base de datos me inscribe solo 1 me gustaria que saliesen los 5

Comment: Pues entonces haz lo que te indico al principio de mi respuesta, y mueve la línea del `$sql_ins` dentro del `for`, **pero tambien** la de su ejecución, claro, que no has puesto donde la tienes

Comment: ah de acuerdo la inserto dentro del for, gracias!